# Trouble Moving Array Elements in Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In my program, I'm using binary search to find where an element should belong, putting it in its correct place and shifting the elements over one space to the right so the array is still ordered. I can find where it belongs with my binary, but I'm having trouble putting it in its correct place and shifting the other elements. The elements are read from a text file one at a time (insert in order) so ideally it will behave like: 17 comes --> [17,..],65 comes -->[17,65,..], 20 comes -->[17,20,65,..], etc. My output is completely wrong. With my code the output is: 41 55 48 34 84 78 89 94 61 108 74 76 97 62 121 119 132 110 144 156 160 146 164 170 75 which is completely out of order :(

Here's my code:

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int cnt, int newVal )
{
    //arr is assumed to be big enough for values + it's an empty array
    int binaryIndex = bSearch(arr,cnt,newVal); //returns a negative value if not duplicate
    int positiveIndex = (-(binaryIndex))-1; //transforms binaryIndex into a positive value of the correct index where number belongs
    for (int i = arr.length-1;i>=positiveIndex;i--){
        if (i<=0)break;
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
    }
    arr[positiveIndex]=newVal;
}
```

Here's my bSearch:

```
public static int bSearch(int[] a, int cnt, int key)
{
    int high = cnt-1;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = (high+low)/2;

    while (low <= high) {

        if (key==a[mid]){
            return mid;
        }
        else if (key < a[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
            mid = (high+low)/2;
        }
        else {
            low = mid +1;
            mid = (high+low)/2;
        }

    }
    return -(mid+1); 

}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong without your implementation of bSearch. The other code seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: What is `bSearch`? In particular, what does it return if the value isn't present?

Comment: bSearch is a method that returns where the element should be put in the array. It's basically a modified binary search.

Comment: Please check the indices returned by `bSearch` and confirm whether the problems occur in `bSearch` or at the insertion.

Comment: bSearch works. My insertion doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning -(mid+1), I needed to return -(low+1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for`-loop has to break at `i>binaryIndex`, otherwise you move the element which is one place left of the target position to the target position where your new element is placed after that.

Comment: I got this output after changing the break statement: 94 121 144 0 146 78 119 160 164 170 0 0 0 74 84 0 0 0 0 48 55 76 97 0 0 :/

Comment: I assume, `positiveIndex` should by `binaryIndex` and it is a typo? And please additionally check the `bSearch`-algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some of your code to get the correct output. Please find the code below :-

```
public class StackOverflow {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    // Just to try the case I am passing the hard-coded value
    insertInOrder(intArray,lengthArray(intArray),50);
    insertInOrder(intArray,lengthArray(intArray),60);
    insertInOrder(intArray,lengthArray(intArray),55);
    insertInOrder(intArray,lengthArray(intArray),50);
    //Displaying the sorted array output
    for(int intA : intArray) {
        System.out.println("Sorted intResultArray" + intA);
    }   
}
// To return the exact count of element in array. I hope you are not inserting 0 as a value because I have use default value. The reason to do it is that default length property of ARRAY will return the actual size of array
// to get the exact count of element
public static int lengthArray(int[] intArrLen) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < intArrLen.length - 1;i++) {
        if(intArrLen[i] != 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
public static void insertInOrder(int[] arr, int count, int newVal ) // Here 'count' refers to exact count of element in array
{
    int binaryIndex = bSearch(arr,count,newVal);
    if (arr[arr.length - 1] == 0) {      // I have added to ensure that there is enough space to move element further down the array
        for (int i = lengthArray(arr);i > binaryIndex;i--) {
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no space to move element in array");
    }
    arr[binaryIndex]=newVal;
}
public static int bSearch(int[] a, int cnt, int key) {
    int high = cnt-1;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    if(high == -1) {
        return low;
    } else {
        mid = (high+low)/2;
    }
    while (low <= high) {
        if (key==a[mid]){
            return (mid + 1);   // I am returning 'mid + 1' in case if number already exist
        }
        else if (key < a[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
            mid = (high+low)/2;
        }
        else {
            low = mid +1;
            mid = (high+low)/2;
        }
    }
    return (mid+1);
    }
}
```

Output :-

```
Sorted intResultArray50
Sorted intResultArray50
Sorted intResultArray55
Sorted intResultArray60
Sorted intResultArray0
Sorted intResultArray0
Sorted intResultArray0
Sorted intResultArray0
Sorted intResultArray0
Sorted intResultArray0
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! But I solved my problem. I was supposed to use low instead of mid for my bSearch.